# Getting the public IP address

Tags: c#

so i am trying to make an application that tells you your public ip address and i have got it to work but when offline it just breaks the program, i want to make it say in a text box "no connection" instead of just breaking.. this is what i have so far.

```
private string getMyIPAddress()
{
    string Address = "";
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://checkip.dyndns.com");
    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        Address = stream.ReadToEnd();
    }
    int first = Address.IndexOf("Address: ") + 9;
    int last = Address.IndexOf("</body>");
    Address = Address.Substring(first, last - first);
    textBox4.Text = Address;

    return Address;
}
```

Comment: Well.... have you ever heard of [try-catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch)?

Comment: When the connection is down, you will probably get a `WebException` with `.Status = WebExceptionStatus.NameResolutionFailure`. But you could also get a `System.Exception` with `HResult = COR_E_INVALIDOPERATION (0x80131509)`. So, don't just catch `WebException`.